# How does this code filters the same elements

Tags: javascript

I saw someone filter the same elements by this code and couldn't understand so please help understand the if statements

input

```
[[],[2],[2],[2,2],[1],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2,2]]
```

Code

```
    for(let ele of result){
        if(fil[ele])continue;
        fil[ele]=ele
    }
    return Object.values(fil);
```

Output

````
[[1],[2],[],[2,2],[1,2],[1,2,2]]```
````

Comment: If elements already exists, it's not added to the object. In the other case it's added. End of story.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski: I think there's much more to the story than that.  At least these two: the automatic casting of arrays to string, the odd iteration order of Object properties in the presence of strings that look like small integers.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I doubt the order matters

Comment: That conditional statement is really weird. Instead of writing `if (…) continue; …` they should have written `if (…); else …` or really just `if (!…) …`.

Comment: What in particular do you not understand? Did you use a debugger to step through the code?

Comment: @Bergi it's called a guard, it's nothing weird, standard code. Else is rarely used in standard coding.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Guarding a single statement like that is weird. It's useful when you have many lines, and especially when you have many guards, and you want to save on indentation - but not here.

Comment: @Bergi: Order may or may not matter to the coder or the OP, but it is strange that the output retains the input ordering, *except in the case* that the input contains single-valued numeric arrays.  That is, at best, surprising for a dedup operation.

Answer (score 1):

This likely most of the body of a function that looks like this:

```js
const dedup = function (result) {
    const fil = {};

    for (let ele of result){
        if (fil[ele]) continue;
        fil[ele]=ele
    }

    return Object.values(fil);
}
```

The goal is to accept an array of arrays of numbers and return an array of the unique arrays in it.  It will do this by creating a temporary object, and for each item passed to it, convert it to a string, check whether that String is already a key in that object, and if not, assign the key to your current item.  At the end, we just read off the items created by applying `Object .values` to that temporary object.

The thing is, this is depending upon the fully-specified, but obscure conversion of arrays and numbers to strings, and on the strange iteration order of object properties when some of them look like small integers.  It also obscures the difference between number values and strings that look like them.

So, when we call it with `[[],[2],[2],[2,2],[1],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2,2]]`, our first value for `ele` is `[]`.  That is cast to a string, which according to the spec, is just the empty string, `""`.  And we check if our object has the empty string as a key.  It doesn't, so we set it to `[]`, and our temporary object now looks like:

```js
{
  [""]: [],
}
```

Then we get `[2]`, and that's converted into the string `"2"`, which isn't in our object, so we add it, to get an object like this:

```js
{
  [""]: [],
  '2': [2],
}
```

We get `[2]` again, but this time, the object already has a `"2"` key, so we don't do anything.

Next we hit `[2, 2]`, which when forced to be a String, is `"2,2"`.  That is not in the object, and we add it to get

```js
{
  [""]: [],
  '2': [2],
  '2,2': [2, 2],
}
```

Then we hit `[1]`, and there is no `"1"` key, so we add it to get:

```js
{
  [""]: [],
  '2': [2],
  '2,2': [2, 2],
  '1': [1],
}
```

... and we continue with the rest of the items to reach this object:

```js
{
  [""]: [],
  '2': [2],
  '2,2': [2, 2],
  '1': [1],
  '1,2': [1, 2],
  '1,2,2': [1, 2, 2],
}
```

Now we will read the keys off that resulting object and return them.  However, there is a twist.  Object properties (`keys`, `values`, or full `entries`, as well as other miscellaneous iteration techniques) are iterated in an odd order.  They are iterated in the order they were added, *except* those strings that look like positive integers come first, in their integer-equivalent order.  Here that means that the keys `"1"` and `"2"` will come first.  So when we iterate the values, we will get `[1]` and `[2]` first, followed the the others, in the order they were added, yielding, as you noted,

```js
[[1], [2], [], [2, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2, 2]]
```

This is a fairly bizarre deduplication result already, but it gets worse, because it declares as duplicates values that really aren't.  For instance,

```js
dedup ([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, '3'], [[1, 2], 3], ['1,2', 3]])
//=> [[1, 2, 3]]
```

This is not to mention several strange parts of the implementation.  Any `if (condition) continue` followed by `doSomething()` is better written as `if (!condition) doSomething()`, so this would be better:

```js
    for (let ele of result){
        if (!fil[ele]) 
          fil[ele] = ele
    }
```

And the function has inconsistent punctuation, using semicolons for the `continue` and `returns` statements but not the property assignment.

This is fairly strange code for the purpose.  It will work fine on a limited domain of arrays known to contain only numbers, but it takes advantage of some obscure corners of the language to do even that.  And it's very hard to generalize.